# How to get an exception or any sort of feedback while parsing incorrect String to Date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I would like to parse `String` to `Date`. The problem is that if I parse the wrong date like `"2009-02-40"` I don't get any exception (no feedback that I passed wrong date) instead I get `Date` object set to `"2009-01-01"`.

```
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            Date result =  df.parse("2009-02-40");
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How to get an exception when I pass the wrong `Date` like this one above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
         df.setLenient(false); //note the change here
            try {
                Date result =  df.parse("2009-02-40");
                System.out.println(result);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to call `setLenient(false)` on your formater. This causes "strict" checking when parsing takes places. By default, "lenient" is "true; and then some heuristics are used that turn "garbage in" into whatever.

Probably not the best design in the world; but that is how it works.

Answer (score 0):

df.parse("2009-02-40"); will throw ParseException, if the beginning of the specified string cannot be parsed.

For a strict parsing, use **df.setLenient(false);**